# Oracle Query Error while using right outer join

Tags: oracle

I have converted one Mysql query to Oracle and facing the following issue while executing.

Query:

```
select oc.channel_id,
       oc.oc_calendar_date,
       to_number(to_char(oc.oc_calendar_date, 'ww')),
       To_char(oc.oc_calendar_date, 'day') as DAY_WEEK,
       to_number(to_char(oc.oc_calendar_date, 'ww'), 1) -
       to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'ww')), 1),
       (CASE
         when to_number(to_char(oc.oc_calendar_date, 'ww'), 1) =
              to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'ww')), 1) then
          'Current Week'
         else
          ('Prev Wk ' || (to_number(to_char(oc.oc_calendar_date, 'ww')) -
          to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'ww')))))
       end) as datediff,
       oc.Package_ID,
       orddet.order_completion_date as total_count
  from (select tor.channel_id,
               to_date(tor.order_completion_date) as order_completion_date,
               tol.package_id as Package_ID
          from tibom.tom_order                tor,
               tibom.tom_order_lines          tol,
               tibtcare_ppm.tcare_ppm_package tpp
         where tor.order_id = tol.order_id
           and tor.order_type = 'NEW'
           and tor.order_status = 'COMPLETED'
           and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tor.order_completion_date) >=
               EXTRACT(MONTH FROM current_date - 6)
           and tpp.package_id = tol.package_id) orddet
 right outer join (select oc.oc_calendar_date, channel_id, package_id
                     from hob_reports.ods_calendar       oc,
                          tibtcare.tcare_channel_ref     tcr,
                          tibtcare_ppm.tcare_ppm_package tpp
                    where EXTRACT(DAY FROM oc.oc_calender_date) <=
                          EXTRACT(DAY FROM current_date)
                      and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM oc.oc_calendar_date) >=
                          EXTRACT(MONTH FROM current_date - 6)) oc on (to_date(orddet.order_completion_date) =
                                                                      to_date(oc_calendar_date) and
                                                                      oc.channel_id =
                                                                      orddet.channel_id and
                                                                      oc.package_id =
                                                                      orddet.package_id)
```

Error:

```
ORA-00904: "OC"."OC_CALENDER_DATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 30 Column: 46
```

Comment: As error says in line 30 there is probably typo, you have: `oc.oc_calender_date`, should be `oc.oc_calendar_date`.

Comment: Why do you mix implicit and explicit joins? That's bad coding style. Unrelated, but: what datatype do the columns `order_completion_date` and `oc_calendar_date` have? If they are already `DATE` columns, using `to_date()` on them to convert them to a date is totally useless (in fact: wrong)

Comment: as an aside, for ease of reading, you should aim to use different aliases for each of your tables/subqueries - you're using "oc" as an alias twice in the same query, albeit at different scopes. I would suggest calling one of those aliases something else, eg. "oc1"